# Classic Counterfeit coin puzzle with a twist

Tags: algorithm, search

This problem is similar to the classic coin search for a single counterfeit coin that weighs lighter than x number of coins but with a twist in the number of coins that could possibly be fake. The real coins all weigh the same, and the fake coins weigh the same. The fake coins weigh less than the real coins.

The difference in the one I am trying to solve is for when there are at most 2 counterfeits, (i.e There can be possibly, No fake coins, 1 fake coin, or 2 fake coins).

**Example of my attempt:**
My attempt at an earlier part of this problem was figuring out how to find the fake coins if any, when x = 9 # of coins, however you were only allowed to use the weight scale at most 6 times to figure it out.

I started by separating x = 9 coins into groups of 3 and comparing the groups to check for equality (if all groups are = there are no fake coins, since there could be at most 2 fake coins and at least 0 fake coins.) Then going from there to checking inequalities for group 1 with group 2 and group 1 again with group 3. With the possibilities of there being 2 fake coins in group 1,2, or 3, and the other possibility of there being 1 fake coin each in 2 groups such as group 1,2, 1,3 or 2,3. Considering these cases I followed the comparisons, thereby breaking down the comparing of groups into thirds until I get to the final few coins and find the fake coins.

**The problem is:**

In a pile of coins where x amount of coins is ">= 3", how would I go about finding the fake coins while making sure the number of times weighed is O(log base 2 of (n)). And How would I find a generic formula to find the number of weighings required to find at most 2 fakes from an x amount of coins.

Programming this is easy when I can consider all cases and compare each one at a slower speed. However it gets significantly more difficult when considering the amount of times weighed has to be O(log base 2 (n)). I have considered using the number of coins to differentiate how the comparisons will be made such as checking if x amount of coins is an odd or even number of coins, then deciding how to compare. If odd, divide x-1 into 3 groups and put the last coin into a fourth group, then continue down the spiral of comparisons to finally find the fake coins, if there are any at all. I also considered dividing say 100 coins into 33 each and comparing the 3 groups, then getting rid of 1/3 of the coins and running comparisons on the 66 left. I still can't wrap my head around solving how to design a generic algorithm procedure to find the fake coins, and then how to even find a generic formula for comparing the amount of times weighed to log base 2 (n).

Even when n = prime/odd numbers it is difficult to split those coins and check for weight in a general procedure that works with any number n >= 3.

To clarify, I need help with figuring out if/how my earlier attempt/example can be applied to create a general comparison algorithm that will apply to any number of coins where x>=3, while the amount of times weighed is O(log base 2 (n)).

Comment: It seems if you recursively break sub-piles into halves, you can weigh each one to determine either all-real, all-fake, or mixed. Only in the latter case will you need to break down further for that pile to eventually count all fakes.

Comment: *"The real problem is"*, *"if I did the comparisons for 9 coins correctly"*, *"how that can be applied to...*", *"how I would prove that"*: you should be asking only about 1 problem - one question. Now your question is too broad.

Comment: I apologize, I am still getting used to using stackoverflow to learn through questions. The question has been edited to specify 1 main inquiry with an example above it.

Comment: If you have at most 2 light coins, you either (A) find two light piles, and reduce the problem to two smaller (1/3 size) instances of the exactly-1-fake-coin problem; or (B) find one light pile, and reduce the problem to one smaller (1/3 size) instance of the 1-or-2-fake-coins problem; or (C) find no light piles, and you are done.

Comment: So for example if n = 99 coins, I would divide the pile in half (A: 49 B:49 C: 1). And the three possibilities would be A < B, A > B, and A = B. For A = B it means there could be 0 fakes in A,B,C, or there are 2 fakes, 1 in A and 1 in B and C is real, or A and B are real and C is the fake. The possibilities don't solve the problem to any lower if A = B.

Comment: It is much simpler to divide to A=33, B=33 and C=33, and then compare A with B and A with C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `O(log_2 n)` is the same as `O(log_b n)` for any base b>1, the recursive breakdown into thirds suggested by user @n.1.8e9 in the comments fits that requirement. There's no need to consider prime/odd numbers, as long as we can solve for some specified constant number of coins with a constant number of weighings.

Here, let 3 coins be our base case. After weighing all 3 pairings (technically, we can get away with 2 weighings), we will know exactly which of the 3 coins are light, if any. So if we split a pile of 11 coins into thirds of 3 each, we can take the 2 leftover coins, borrow any other coin from the other piles, perform the 3 weighings, and then discard the 2 leftover coins since we know their status. As long as there are `O(log n)` splitting stages, dealing with the leftovers won't affect the asymptotics.

The only complex part of the proof is that after the first step, we go from the '0, 1 or 2 fakes' problem to either two 'exactly 1 fake' subproblems or a '1 or 2 fakes' subproblem. Assuming you know the solution to the original 'exactly 1 fake' problem with `1 + log_3 n` weighings, the proof should look fairly similar.

The procedure for 'at most 2 fake' and '1 or 2 fakes' is the same. Given n coins, we divide them into three groups of `floor(n/3)` coins (and treat any leftovers as we did above). If n <= 3, stop and just perform all weighings. Otherwise, given piles A, B and C, perform the 3 pair weighings (A, B), (A, C) and (B, C).

If they all weigh the same (A=B=C), there are no fake coins.

If one pile is different, there are two cases: the single pile is lighter or heavier than the other two.

If it is lighter (say, A < B, A < C, and B = C), then pile A has exactly 1 or 2 fake coins and we have a single problem instance on n/3 coins (discard piles B and C).

If the outlier is heavier (say, A = B, A < C, and B < C), then piles A and B have exactly one fake coin each, which is the standard counterfeit problem.

To prove the bound on number of weighings, you probably need to use induction. Each recursion level requires at most 6 weighings, so an upper bound formula for the number of weighings required when there may be up to 2 fake coins remaining is `T(n) = max(T(n/3), 2 * (1 + log_3(n/3))) + 6`, where the `1 + log_3 (n/3)` term is the standard upper bound with perfect strategy to find one light coin among `n/3` coins (where we take the floor of all divisions to get integers).